# Converting Byte To Int,Short To Long...etc

Tags: java

I'm Learning Java and Don't know much about it.
What is the formula of converting from bigger data types to smaller ones?For example:

```
byte x=10;
long y=250;
x=(byte)y;
System.out.println(x);
```

after compiling it gives me -6.
and what uses does it have?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting -6 because you made a long to a byte and the value in the long was too big for the byte.  Try to convert a byte to a long!

A byte has a range from -128 to 127. A long goes from -2^63 to 2^63-1. You have gotten an overflow becuase of your converting in this way.

Answer (score 0):

a byte can only store at most 256 values however because java is signed, a byte in java stores from -128 to 127.

Your value of 250 is over 127, so it wraps around to negative numbers.

**What is the formula of converting smaller data types to bigger ones?**

I think you had your variables backwards

```
y=x;
```

you don't need to cast since a byte will automatically be expanded into  a long

Answer (score 0):

The `byte` datatype is a signed 1-byte value that may take on values from -128 to 127. When you convert `250l` to a `byte`, Java looks at the binary value `11111010` and shoves that in the `byte`, but because that first bit is a 1, it's interpreted as a negative value. If you run `11111010` through 2's-complement, you get `110` or 6, so `11111010` is -6.

Short answer: Converting larger datatypes to smaller one gives you hinky results. Don't do it without significant error-checking.